# what is use of id attribute in <sevlet id=" "> tag in web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web.xml

What is use of id attribute in  tag in **web.xml** file in web dynamic project?? And why there is **xsinps** and **schema-location** even though it assign globally in  tag??

[The file screenshot from eclips IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dvQY.jpg)

Comment: All XML elements have an `id` attribute . It isn't documented to have any specific meaning in `web.xml` files. Yor screen shot should have been posted in your question, and as text, not as a picture,

Comment: @EJP -  I know that "xml:id" is standard (as of 2005), but is "id"?  Can you provide a spec reference for this?

Answer (score 2):

> what is use of id attribute in  tag in web.xml?

AFAIK the `<servlet>` element does not have an `id` attribute.  Certainly it is not documented in the specifications; see https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf for example.

It is most likely ignored.

> And why there is "xsinps" and "schema-location" even though it assign globally in tag??

I've never heard of `xsinps` attributes.  (Perhaps you mean "xmlns"?)

An "xmlns" and "schema-location" will be present because they are required in each and every XML file where the corresponding namespace prefix is use.  That is basic XML stuff ....

Comment: Please look at above screenshot for servlet tag showing id and other attribute

Comment: Yes.  That just means that Eclipse *thinks* that there should / could be an `id` attribute.  The spec disagrees, and what the spec says is definitive.